# Spring Cloud Config Server requires restart on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spring-cloud-config

I am running a spring cloud config server through AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Everything seems to work fine, but after some time (around 2 weeks) I encounter problems accessing the configurations. I get the error

> Loading configuration failed

without further details on the "Whitelabel error" page of spring boot (when accessing the configuration through the browser; access through client just times out).

When I restart the config server instance on Elastic Beanstalk I can access the configuration normally again (no repository/code changes, just restart).

I suppose this is not expected behavior - I don't believe there is a "timeout" on the config server after which a restart is required.

Could it have something to do with AWS?

Comment: Nothing in the logs of the config service either?

Comment: @g00glen00b did not log to file yet, started that now - that will dfinitely help.